# Magento - First class / method

Tags: magento

I would like to add a registry item at the very start of the all the front-end (and maybe admin) page calls (any kind catalogue, cms, controllers, etc). I want to add:

```
$myRegistry = new stdClass();
Mage::register('myRegistry',$myRegistry);
```

Which is the best class / method to overriding?

Ie which class / method is executed for every front-end call (and possibly admin too)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an observer for the controller_action_predispatch event, that will run before any page is built.

If you need help creating an observer, you can find information on that here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method